# No-ip Client not downloading by command wget (Error 403 Forbidden)

Tags: raspbian

My raspberry's OS is Raspbian Screch.

When i enter command "wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
" to download the No-ip client, i get the following error message :

" http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
Resolving www.no-ip.com (www.no-ip.com)... 8.23.224.110
Connecting to www.no-ip.com (www.no-ip.com)|8.23.224.110|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-12-27 17:57:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden."

Does anyone knows how to fix this ???

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please visit the helpcenter and take the tour to learn how Stackexchange works. 403 does sound like an error on the far side, i.e. not your Pi but the server that hosts this file. Try again at a later time (as they usually say). Sidenote: those binaries seem to be for the 686 and x86-64 architecture, not the Pi's ARM.

Comment: @Ghanima Thank you for your response. I how can i visit helpcenter ?? I don't see anything on the menu about helpcenter. I know Error 403 is a server-side error. But after i have done some search regarding my problem, i discovered that there might be some problem on my side, that cause the server to reply back with error 403. Regarding the sidenote: thank you for telling me this. I'll try another Linux distro. vielen dank

Comment: It's https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/ and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour/ Please note that you may post (and accept) your own answer if your research comes up with a solution... so feel free.

Comment: @Ghanima Thank you for posting the two links. After reading them, i believe my question is on the wrong section/stack. Should i go to the Linux StackExchange ?

Comment: @Ghanima BTW, it turns out that Raspbian does run No-ip client. There are people who have done it. Regarding Error 403, i tried to download the file at a later time as you suggested, but it is still display Error 403. So, should i move my question to Linux's stack ?

Comment: If you're trying to run it on a Pi it is on-topic here and no need to move to U&L.